# Angular 2 app not working on Apache HTTP Server

Tags: apache, angular

I copied my Angular 2 app on the Apache HTTP Server 2.4 in the htdocs folder, but it doesn't work.

**index.html:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Angular 2 app</title>
   <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
   <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

If I try to open the index.html page in the browser, I see only the text "Loading...." in my browser.
The Angular 2 App is not displayed.

How can I fix this?

It works on my local environment right, where I am using Angular CLI. I need to find a way to make it work on the Apache HTTP Server 2.4.
The only thing I have to do locally is to run `npm start`.

Comment: Are you using angular-cli to serve it locally?

Comment: Yes, locally I am using angular-cli. The only thing i am doing locally is to run "npm start".

Answer (score 8):

you just need to add a point in the base href `<base href="./">`

Comment: Works for me! Thanks

Comment: Works for me also

Comment: This works for me, too! To prevent overwriting the file, specify `--base-href` in `ng build` instead of manually editing the generated file: `ng build --base-href './'`.

Comment: Spent a great deal searching for this! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a Build if you are planning to run your app on a remote server. Use the 'ng build' command (stop npm start first). ng build will create a distributable build in the 'dist' folder in your project. You can copy the contents of this folder to your remote server.

Answer (score 0):

First, install Angular CLI in your dev environnement (if not done already)

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

Run this command to build a dist version of your project

```
ng build -prod
```

copy/paste the content of dist folder into the root of your local (or online) apache server

Comment: How is that a different answer than my answer?

Comment: My answer just provide more details as @Alexandru seems to be new in angular world.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular-cli follow this steps:

1. you need build your app for production run (this generate a folder with the name of your app) :

> ```
>   ng build -prod --output-path=[appname]-bh /appname/
> ```

2. copy your app folder into root apache server path : /var/www/html/

That's all

Regards,

Fernando.