# Change The context path for angular in angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular

When a generate The dist directory with angular cli i need put this in root directory of server for example:

Localhost:8080/

For run correctly The angular 2 app

But if i want put in other directory how for example:

Localhost:8080/dist
I got error in js files because The app find this in / root Rute

Any ideas how change The contexto path??

Thanks

Comment: you config files?

Comment: Is The default of any angular cli angular app

Comment: firstly why do you want to modify that ?

Comment: For localhost/angularapp1 localhost/angularapp2  but angular cli dist directory onlyworks in root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in 
[Angular 2 app not working on Apache HTTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765324/angular-2-app-not-working-on-apache-http-server)
supergirl recommend change the base ref in index.html
and yes this works

```
 <base href="./">
```

Update : this problem resolve but with bug in path large produce The same error 404  in refresh page